# How do I put a caption under an image in a table?

Tags: image, tabular, captions

I am using tables to create a grid of movie posters, the only problem is how do I put a caption under each image without affecting the images alignment or anything else? Let me know

Comment: Can you post your current code?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/795wu/